# Multithreaded increment understanding ordering

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I do not know why the code below works. The part I am stuck at is

```
for t in worker_threads:
    t.join()
```

To me, all this does is wait for each `worker` thread to `.put(1)` into `counter_queue`.

I'm not quite sure the purpose of these lines as `del t` destroys them right away. I might be missing the significance of these repeated lines:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=print_manager)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
del t
```

Is there something I a missing regarding the `.daemon` flag? or is there something else?

```
import threading, queue

###########################################################################################

counter = 0

counter_queue = queue.Queue()

def counter_manager():
    'I have EXCLUSIVE rights to update the counter variable'
    global counter

    while True:
        increment = counter_queue.get()
        counter += increment
        print_queue.put([
            'The count is %d' % counter,
            '---------------'])
        counter_queue.task_done()

t = threading.Thread(target=counter_manager)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
del t

###########################################################################################

print_queue = queue.Queue()

def print_manager():
    'I have EXCLUSIVE rights to call the "print" keyword'
    while True:
        job = print_queue.get()
        for line in job:
            print(line)
        print_queue.task_done()

t = threading.Thread(target=print_manager)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
del t

###########################################################################################

def worker():
    'My job is to increment the counter and print the current count'
    counter_queue.put(1)

print_queue.put(['Starting up'])
worker_threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    worker_threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in worker_threads:
    t.join()

counter_queue.join()
print_queue.put(['Finishing up'])
print_queue.join()
```

output:

```
Starting up
The count is 1
---------------
The count is 2
---------------
The count is 3
---------------
The count is 4
---------------
The count is 5
---------------
The count is 6
---------------
The count is 7
---------------
The count is 8
---------------
The count is 9
---------------
The count is 10
---------------
Finishing up
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out i had a misunderstanding of the functionality of `del`. `del` actually dereferences the object/thread. It still exists in the background and still running and listening for input!